# Can I restore recent query output in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a large query I am running in Oracle SQL Developer.  The query seemed to run successfully and then I made the mistake of hitting `count rows` and it froze.  I had to terminate the program in the task manager.  I have been searching online and I have seen a lot about how unsaved scripts can be recovered using history, but I dont see anything about restoring the query result.  Is it cashed anywhere so I dont have to run the query all over again?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure that the results are not being saved anywhere. Why don't you run the query again?

Comment: I just dont want to wait that long : /

Comment: Can you add the query + execution plan + some information about data volumes?

Comment: hmm, I'll play with that.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: it did run successfully - if you had a grid to do a count rows on - when you ask for count rows, we run the QUERY AGAIN, to get the row count for your results - you would have had to wait awhile for the answer...the maybe safer thing to have done was to do a ctrl+end to get all the rows fetched to the client - assuming it wasn't 18 billion or something ridiculous

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, Coincidentally after I asked this question I read your article on ctrl+end before exporting.  That's a great tip, thanks twice : )

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, So i tried your method a couple times and the query fails every time saying 'gc overhead limit exceeded', any ideas?

Comment: yes @HunterClark get fewer rows OR increase the jvm heap size (give it more memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PL/SQL Developer, then you need to press CTRL+E. You can find Recent Executed Quer